# Server Certificate Extension and interface with Android

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Our Android application is interfacing with a server than employs a certificate chain, with certificates issued by Verisign. We were able to establish SSL sessions with this endpoint so far. This Verisign certificate is due to expire next month.

Questions:
1. Should Server site get a new certificate reissued from Verisign and everything would just work?
2. Can the original certificate expiration date be just extended rather than issue a new one?

What can be done to ensure a smooth transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be issued a new certificate, but it needn't be issued by Verisign.  *Any* trusted authority can sign the certificate.

The key store containing trusted issuers is here:

```
/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks
```

Comment: I understand that; however, we have a certain version of the app out with our customers that trusts these certificates from Verisign. We want to undergo this transition without much hassle and therefore, dont want to change the CA.

Comment: What happens if the Verisign CA is ever compromised or expires?  You should always use the platform trust store unless you have a really good reason not to (IMHO).

Comment: that point is well understood. However, for this one build "if extending Verisign cert is the only option" what should be the steps undertaken?

Comment: @Samuh in that case, just get a new certificate from Verisign and ask the server administrator to replace it.

Comment: Re the trust store location: this is not the case as of ICS as later. Using the platform trust store is not always a good idea: it has a lot of CAs, and you are vulnerable as soon as _any_ of those gets compromised. Limiting who you trust (certificate pinning) might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot extend a certificate, but you shouldn't need to. As long as the server certificate is issued by a CA you trust (does not to be VeriSign), things should continue to work. You might want to replace the cert sooner rather than later though, because people might have clocks that are off by a few days.